# How to get StyledDocument.insertString() to update better

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

I have a background Thread that gets text data from an InputStream
and tries to insert it into a JTextPane:

```
iLen = doc.getLength();
doc.insertString(iLen, lineS, normalStyle);

if ( iLen > 0 )
    textPane.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength() - 1);
```

Basically my problem is that a lot of the time text
is coming through, and it's calling this section of code,
but nothing gets drawn till a large section of text has come through.

I understand that a lot is going on behind the scenes
and I don't have any Listener or anything.

So is there any fairly simple way I can get it to draw
almost every time that it's called?

Or at least more often than it is now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `textPane.repaint()`
after setting the position of the caret.

Comment: I tried adding it, and the results seem inconsistent.  Sometimes I'm seeing about a dozen small lines go through it and it doesn't draw anything, it draws them all at the end, and other times, it's drawing almost every line, but if I comment it out, I get nearly the same result.  Is there any way to use Element, or anything, to affect how often it draws the text?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it in `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` to let EDT execute the insert related changes processing.